# Splitting a comma and space separated input into two words

Tags: java, string

I am having difficulty splitting a string of user input into two words. The string is in the format "word1, word2", and I am trying to create two separate strings of word1 and word2. Here is my attempt:

```
System.out.println("Enter the two words separated by a comma, or 'quit':");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String input = sc.next();

while(!input.equals("quit")){
    input.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    System.out.println(input);  //testing

    int index1 = input.indexOf(",");

    String wordOne = input.substring(0, index1);

    String wordTwo = input.substring(index1+1, input.length() );

    if(wordOne.length()!=wordTwo.length()){
           System.out.println("Sorry, word lengths must match.");
       }

    System.out.println("Enter the two words separated by a comma, or 'quit':"); 

    input = sc.next();
}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter the two words separated by a comma, or 'quit':  
leads, golds  
leads,  
Sorry, word lengths must match.  
Enter the two words separated by a comma, or 'quit':  
golds  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1  
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)  
    at Solver.main(Solver.java:22) //this points to the line "String wordOne = input.substring(0, index1);"
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: assign the result back to input `input = input.replaceAll("\\s+","");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `sc.next()` instead of `sc.nextLine()`. I can see that in your input you are entering "leads, gold" where leads, is followed by a space. In this case `sc.next()` will return just "leads," and not "leads, gold"

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try:

```
input.split(",");
```

This will give you an String array. From JavaDocs.

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

**Update:** Since, you are using `sc.next()` which will take a single word unless it sees a space at which it will terminate the input. You should instead use `sc.nextLine()` to keep the complete input as user inputs.

`next()`

> `public java.lang.String next()` 
>   Finds and returns the next complete
>   token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by
>   input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while
>   waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext
>   returned true.

`nextLine()`

> `public java.lang.String nextLine()`
>
> Advances this scanner past the
>   current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method
>   returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at
>   the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line. Since
>   this method continues to search through the input looking for a line
>   separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to
>   skip if no line separators are present.

Comment: He is getting an Exception and he needs help with addressing that. And the exception is not because of him trying to replace comma with a space but because he i not reading the whole input but a partial one instead.

Comment: @user3493289 because he is trying to implement manual algorithm instead of resuing already developed and provided by String

Comment: But your solution doesnt help address the Exception that he is getting. The exception is because of using sc.next() instead of sc.nextLine(). Improvements to his algorithm should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Exception is appearing because of this `String wordTwo = input.substring(index1+1, input.length() );` not because of `sc.next();`. Please look again and debug if you want to in your IDE

Comment: Anyways, updated the answer to cover that scenario as well. Thank you

Comment: Exception is happening in that line because he didn't use sc.nextLine(). You can replace sc.next() with sc.nextLine() and you will notice that no exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not know the difference between next() and nextLine()